# Git Bash error while running command --- git config --global -e

Tags: git, notepad++, git-bash

I am new to git and github and trying to integrate notepad++ with git bash. I followed all the steps and at the final step when I am running the following command, i get the error. Could any one please help.

```
 git config --global -e

$ git config --global -e
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... C:/Notepad++/notepad++.ex -multiInst -nosession: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
C:/Notepad++/notepad++.ex -multiInst -nosession: -c: line 0: `C:/Notepad++/notepad++.ex -multiInst -nosession "$@"'
error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:/Notepad++/notepad++.ex -multiInst -nosession'.
```

Comment: **hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...**; Are you sure the file isn't opened anywhere else?

Comment: I suspect `C:/Notepad++/notepad++.ex` must be `C:/Notepad++/notepad++.exe`. Edit your `%HOME%\.gitconfig` without `git` and fix `[core]editor`. Or `SET GIT_EDITOR=C:/Notepad++/notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession` and then repeat `git config --global -e`